# Private Headers issue compiling QtWebKit 5.212 against Qt 5.10.1

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, qtwebkit

On Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, I'm building QtWebKit (5.212) against Qt 5.10.1, and I'm running into an error during the configuration part of the build.

Here is the command line I use:

```
perl Tools\Scripts\build-webkit --qt --release --only-webkit --no-ninja --cmakeargs="-Thost=x64 -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64" -G \"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64\" --prefix=E:\Qt-5.10.1\QtWebKitBin -v
```

Here is the error:

```
-- Performing Test Qt5Gui_PRIVATE_HEADER_FOUND
-- Performing Test Qt5Gui_PRIVATE_HEADER_FOUND - Failed
CMake Error at Source/cmake/OptionsQt.cmake:75 (message):
  Header private/qhexstring_p.h is not found.  Please make sure that:

      1. Private headers of Qt5Gui are installed
      2. Qt5Gui_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS is correctly defined in Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Source/cmake/OptionsQt.cmake:612 (CHECK_QT5_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  Source/cmake/WebKitCommon.cmake:50 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:139 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The private header that it's using to do the test does exist in the Qt5 include directory, as one would expect, in this location:

```
E:\Qt-5.10.1\QtBin\include\QtGui\5.10.1\QtGui\private\qhexstring_p.h
```

The Qt5GuiConfig.cmake file exists only in the `E:\Qt-5.10.1\QtBin\lib\cmake\Qt5Gui` directory of the Qt installation (not in the QtWebKit source installation).  I don't know if it's making use of this in any way.

What do I need to do to make the build find this directory as desired?  Adding 'include\QtGui\5.10.1\QtGui\' to the INCLUDE env var doesn't work, but I don't believe that's the correct solution anyway.

Here are the parts of my environment related to the Qt directories:

```
INCLUDE = ...;E:\Qt-5.10.1\QtBin\include;E:\Qt-5.10.1\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\include
LIB = ...;E:\Qt-5.10.1\QtBin\lib;E:\Qt-5.10.1\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\lib
PATH = E:\Qt-5.10.1\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtbase\bin;E:\Qt-5.10.1\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\gnuwin32\bin;E:\Qt-5.10.1\QtBin\bin;...
```

`QtBin` is the directory with my compiled Qt 5.10.1.

`qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1` is the Qt 5.10.1 source package

Thanks in advance for any help.  I couldn't find any answers searching Google or StackOverflow.

Comment: It is the proper place of `Qt5GuiConfig.cmake` file under the QT installation: This file describes QT, not a QTWebKit. You may try to find variable `Qt5Gui_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS` in that file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks for this.  After comparing my Qt build to another one I had access to, I added settings to the Qt5Gui_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS in that file, but it didn't make a difference to the QtWebKit build.  
What is it that references that file from the QtWebKit build?  
How does it search for that file?  
How does it make use of it?
Why would my build not have this set automatically?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the wiki](https://github.com/annulen/webkit/wiki/Building-QtWebKit-on-Windows), you should try to define CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to point to your Qt installation

For example :

```
perl Tools\Scripts\build-webkit --qt --release --only-webkit --no-ninja --cmakeargs="-Thost=x64 -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015" -G \"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64\" --prefix=E:\Qt-5.10.1\QtWebKitBin -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Build on Windows using build-webkit fails because it was unable to find the location for this header file qhexstring_p.h. How to fix this error and although is not a standard way but it works.

1. Located the file qhexstring_p.h in your prefix directory, or your
   preferred Qt Installation SDK
2. Go to this file Source\cmake\OptionsQt.cmake and change this

> From this CHECK_QT5_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS(Gui private/qhexstring_p.h)

to this below

> CHECK_QT5_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS(Gui
>   C:/SDK/qt5-5.7.0-vs2015/qt5-x86-static-release/include/QtGui/5.7.0/QtGui/private/qhexstring_p.h)

The path here must match the path to your Qt installation and to the exact location the missing file is located. This ensures the test to look for the private director for the Qt installation is successful.

Then locate the file Qt5GuiConfig.cmake in your Qt installation directory and set the variable Qt5Gui_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS to the location were you private headers are found with this below.

```
set(Qt5Gui_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS "${_qt5Gui_install_prefix}/include/QtGui/${Qt5Gui_VERSION_STRING}/QtGui" "${_qt5Gui_install_prefix}/include/QtCore/${Qt5Gui_VERSION_STRING}/QtCore")
```

> And note this version QtWebKit (5.212) of is known to have several
>   bugs, so its best you go for those stable ones.

The Save and run

```
perl Tools\Scripts\build-webkit --qt --release --only-webkit --no-ninja --cmakeargs="-Thost=x64 -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015" -G \"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64\" --prefix=E:\Qt-5.10.1\QtWebKitBin -v
```

As you wanted, that should be able to run as expected.